# Search bar with a foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I am confronted with a difficult problem. I would like to create a search bar.
I have 4 fields in my table **feedbacks**, id, instruction, description, fk_candidat.

If enter a value of my field 'instruction', I get correctly my recording.
[image]

Now, I would rather that the user enters the **name** instead of **instruction**.

My second table named **candidats** and I have 3 fields id, name, firstname.

Do you have an idea to combine the fk_name (feedbacks) to name (candidats).

Here is an idea of my code.

```
public function index(Request $req){

     if($req->search == ""){
            $feedbacks = Feedback::paginate(5);
           return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
     } else {
          $feedbacks = Feedback::where('instruction', 'LIKE', '%' .$req->search . '%')
        ->paginate(3);
        $feedbacks->appends($req->only('search'));
        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
     }  

    }
```

My HTLM

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
<div class="input-group add-on">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Recherche..." name="search" id="search" type="text">
<div class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Edit: 
I should use the function **whereHas**, but I don't know the syntax?

```
public function index(Request $req){

     if($req->search == ""){
            $feedbacks = Feedback::paginate(5);
           return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
     } else {
          $feedbacks = Feedback::whereHas('candidats.name', 'LIKE', '%' .$req->search . '%')
        ->paginate(3);
        $feedbacks->appends($req->only('search'));
        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
     }  

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You've got a couple methods. If you're using Laravel relationships, you can query the relationship between `Feedback` and `Candidate`, using `->whereHas()` instead of `->where()`. If you're not, you can do a simple `->join()`, and modify the `->where()` to check for `candidate.name` instead of `instruction`. Both methods are little broad for what you have currently though; see if you can implement an attempt, and modify the question if you run into a more specific issue.

Comment: @Tim Lewis: Thank you, I should use the function whereHas() but I don't know the syntax. I have edited my first message. Do you have a little idea? Thanks

Comment: A very quick, simple google search for "Laravel whereHas()" reveals the following: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence... That being said, do you have the relationship set up between `Feedback` and `Candidate`?

Comment: @Tim Lewis: Yes, I have a relationship between Feedback and Candidat, I going see the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a one-to-many relationship exists between Candidat and Feedback, you can use Laravel's `->whereHas()` method to query like below

```
if($req->search == ""){
 $feedbacks = Feedback::paginate(5);
 return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
} else {
 $feedbacks = Feedback::whereHas('candidats', function($query){
  $query->where('name','LIKE', '%' .$req->search . '%');
 })->paginate(3);
 return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
}
```

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence